# How to generate some links for a paginator in PHP without missing last page?

Tags: php, pagination

This code to generate a paginator isn't working as expected, what could be the problem?

This function obtains the HTML links for a paginator given some data about the results the current page is showing. $ruta is the base URL, $pagina is the current page for which I want to generate pagination links, $limite is the number of result that each page shows, $total is the total of results to be paged.

```
function generarPaginador($ruta, $pagina, $limite, $total)
{
    // Traducciones
    $textoPrimera = _('Primera');
    $textoUltima = _('Última');

    // Variables para la numeración de los enlaces para paginación
    $primera = 1;
    $ultima = ceil($total / $limite); //I was using floor but thanks to the answer I could verify that ceil gives me the correct pagination links for the given parameters
    $anterior = $pagina == 1 ? 1 : $pagina - 1;
    $siguiente = ( ( $pagina + 1) > $ultima) ? $ultima : $pagina + 1;

    if ($ultima == 1) {
        return '';
    }

    // ENLACES: Primeros
    $enlaces = '';
    $enlaces .= "<span><a href=\"$ruta?pag=$primera&max=$limite\">$textoPrimera</a></span>";
    $enlaces .= "<span><a href=\"$ruta?pag=$anterior&max=$limite\">&lt;</a></span>";

    // ENLACES: Previos a la página actual
    $i = ( $pagina - 3) > 0 ? $pagina - 3 : 1;
    while ($i < $pagina) {
        $enlaces .= "<span><a href=\"$ruta?pag=$i&max=$limite\">$i</a></span>";
        $i++;
    }

    // ENLACES: Página actual
    $enlaces .= "<span class=\"current\">$pagina</span>";

    // ENLACES: Siguientes a la página actual
    $i = $pagina + 1;
    $tamano = $pagina + 3;
    while (($i <= $ultima ) && ($i <= $tamano)) {
        $enlaces .= "<span><a href=\"$ruta?pag=$i&max=$limite\">$i</a></span>";
        $i++;
    }

    // ENLACES: Últimos enlaces
    $enlaces .= "<span><a href=\"$ruta?pag=$siguiente&max=$limite\">&gt;</a></span>";
    $enlaces .= "<span><a href=\"$ruta?pag=$ultima&max=$limite\">$textoUltima</a></span>";

    return $enlaces;
}
```

For example I want to generate the links of the paginator for the **page 2**, there are **37 total results**, but the web page just shows **10 results per page**. The base url is **/busqueda/resultados/**

If I pass those parameters to the function it generates 3 links without problem for the 3 first pages with the first 30 results, but it should also generate a 4th link for the last page (because each page contains 10 max, the first three contains 10 each one, 30 in total, but the 4th contains the remaining 7 and there should be a link to it).

Comment: Why would you be passing the number of results into the function?

Comment: I do a count of some rows in a database table, then after that, I pass the result of the count to this function so it can generate the links of the paginator for the given SQL query. So I need to pass the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be as simple as changing floor to ceil.

Comment: It works! I feel something bad for not noticing that before ¬¬
Thanks for the answer!